# How to implement snowflake connector with structured streaming in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spark-structured-streaming

Currently I have code that takes the input and creates a data stream. My goal is to have the data uploading to snowflake. Currently I am trying this, is there an easier way to go about this. Or is it possible to have this write to a pandas df and then upload the pandas df to snowflake? It has previously worked just with structured streaming and no connection to snowflake.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sfconn = {
    "sfURL": f"{os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT')}.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfUser": os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_USER'),
    "sfPassword": os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD'),
    "sfDatabase": "x",
    "sfSchema": "x",
    "sfWarehouse": "x"
}

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("snowflake-connector")\
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
              .readStream\
              .format('json') \
              .schema(spark_schemas['x']) \
              .load(f"s3a://{x_path}")

out = df \
    .writeStream\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .option("dbtable", "scratch_table")\
    .options(sfconn)\
    .trigger(processingTime='1 minutes')\
    .format("snowflake")\
    .start()
```

Right now it's showing

```
options() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

and

```
 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: snowflake.
```

Answer (score 0):

First error is following - `options` take the variable number of pairs that specify [options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.options).  If you have option as map, you need to "[unpack](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#unpacking-with-the-asterisk-operators)" it using the `**map` syntax, like here:

```py
opts = {'inferSchema': "true", "header": "false"}
df = spark.read.options(**opts)
   .format("csv")
   .schema("ticker String,date Date, price Float")
   .load(".../datasets/dow-quotes.csv")
```

For 2nd error - you just need to specify correct name of the connector - `net.snowflake.spark.snowflake` instead of `snowflake`, and make sure that Snowflake Spark connector is specified when you submitting the job. See Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#configuring-the-pyspark-script) for more details.